# Handling image upload exceptions

Tags: media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Theming Drupal fatal error messages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20876/theming-drupal-fatal-error-messages)

Whenever a user upload an image that doesn't match the requirements, Drupal throws an exception.

How can I customize the message, and the style of that page?

Comment: Please show what Drupal is telling you.