# Theming Drupal fatal error messages

Tags: theming

Whenever Drupal encounters an unrecoverable error, it displays an error message.

Is there a way I can provide a template for this page?

Comment: Can you give an example of a *Drupal* error that you are talking about, or are you talking about a fatal *PHP* error?

Comment: Are you missing gramatical php marks like a semi-colon, comma or quotations?

Comment: He's talking about exceptions which are thrown and caught. This could be PDO exceptions (database error) or entity wrapper exceptions and a host of other exceptions which are caught and Drupal show an fatal error page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing you come by is the `maintenance-page.tpl.php`, It doesn't cover all cases, but if things go wrong but not that wrong that Drupal can't post a page, it uses `maintenance-page.tpl.php` to display the error(s).

The error itself is displayed using `drupal_set_message`

Comment: And for Drupal 8 this would be something like maintenance-page.twig ? Do you know?